# Make templateHelpers wait until async function ends in Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, marionette, data-synchronization

I'm using the [Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/es/1.0.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html) plugin of phonegap in a `Marionette` `ItemView`, but could be any asynchronous stuff. I just want to pass a variable throw the template helper, which has to wait until (in this case) DB operations end.

I also tryed putting the asynchronous piece of code inside the `templateHelpers` function, but it does not wait, and the `value` variable is empty in the template.

```
initialize: function(options){
    that=this;
    var db = window.openDatabase("MyDB", "1.0", "My Database", 200000);
    db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyDB (id unique, name, value)');
        var query = "SELECT * FROM MyDB WHERE id="+that.model.get('id')+" LIMIT 1";
        tx.executeSql(query, [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }

    function errorCB(err) {
        alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }

    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
        var len = results.rows.length;
        if(len>0)
            that.value = results.rows.item(0).value;
    }                             

},

templateHelpers: function(){
    var helperParams = {};
    var val = {"value": this.value };
    _.extend(helperParams, val);
    return helperParams;
},
```

Any ideas?

Comment: re-define templateHelpers hash on querySuccess ?

Comment: thanks @Evgeniy, could you give me an example?

Comment: I could make it work adding to the query success this two lines: `that.templateHelpers();` `that.render();` Did you mean that? I see it like a bit tricky solution. Anyway,if you give it as an answer, I will tick it ;)

Comment: It doesn't make sense to try to make templateHelpers async. The easiest way to accomplish what you probably want is to just render the view again in your success handler.

Comment: One more question - what exact data you get from DB ? is it relevant to model? I mean what about to add some additional fields to model and get rid of templateHelpers and just listen to model.change ?

Comment: @AndrewHubbs Ok, I was thinking that rendering the view again, it was going to fire again the `initialize` method, but that was the solution. Thanks! @Evgeniy, yes I really need to do that, because I have some information that needs to be stored and readed without internet connection.

Comment: check out @Evgeniy's comment - certainly seems like the way to go

Comment: @EliranMalka, what do you mean? I made it work rendering the view again on query success as explained on comments.

Comment: oh i get it - post it as an answer than, for the benefit of others :)

Comment: @cor why use an MV* framework if you're not sticking to its paradigm? Accessing databases really has no place in a view. Set up a different object which does that, let it update the model and let the view listen to the model's `change` events.

Comment: @Creynders, don't forget that it is a Cordova Phonegap app, so I really need to store some information in the phone. This app needs to work sometimes without internet connection. And yes, I think I can use an MV* framework for my javascript code.

Comment: @cor yeah of course you can store some information on the phone. I didn't say you shouldn't. I just meant you shouldn't do it from a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the solution is to re-render the view after your async load completes. This works because the `render` method in your `Marionette` view will call `templateHelpers` again and specifically will **not** call `initialize` again.

```
function querySuccess(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    if(len>0)
        that.value = results.rows.item(0).value;
    that.render(); // <<< Re-render on success
}
```